# Align 3 images side by side on center of page? HTML

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I know there are a lot of questions like this, and I have tried many of the methods suggested by those who have answered those questions, however, nothing works. I am beginning to think that my methods are not wrong, but that something else in my code is interfering? Such as my `main div`

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it. Currently, my images are just stacked on top of each other (vertically) on the left edge of the container...

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<!-- a bunch of <p> tags here I won't include -->
    <div class="img123">
        <img height="200" width="200" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="some text" class="images"/>
    </div>
    <div class="img123">
        <img height="200" width="200" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="some text" class="images"/>
    </div>
    <div class="img123">
        <img height="200" width="200" src="images/image3.jpg" alt="some text" class="images"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS solution I was trying to use for my images and the `.main div`

```
.image123 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px; 
}

#images{
    text-align:center;
}

.main {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    width: 930px;
    display: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My favourite way is to set up 2 classes site-wide:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

This way you can align stuff easily using these two classes. Row should always be the parent container. Here is how you would handle the html:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col img123">
      <img height="200" width="200" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="some text" class="images"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col img123">
      <img height="200" width="200" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="some text" class="images"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col img123">
      <img height="200" width="200" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="some text" class="images"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you want it evenly spaced use:

```
.col {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nddsvq

Comment: I gave it shot but when I view the page, the images are still aligned to the left and vertically stacked. There must be something going on in my code causing this, beings you were able to easily align them correctly...

Comment: hmm.. you could try putting your code in stack blitz and recreate the issue so can help debug.

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks for the help!

Comment: I finally figured it out! It was because I put each image in their own individual `<div class="col img123">` div. I just stuck all three in a single div and they aligned just right. Thanks for your help though! I still very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>flexbox</title>
    <style>
        .main{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-color:yellow;
            display:flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="image"> <!--1 image-->
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1864189/pexels-photo-1864189.jpeg" width="200" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="image"> <!--2 image-->
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1878095/pexels-photo-1878095.jpeg" width="200" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="image"><!--3 image-->
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/572487/pexels-photo-572487.jpeg" width="200" height="200" >
        </div>
    </div>
         
</body>
</html>
```